# How to change global providers depending on authorization state

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation

In an application, after authorization, it is often necessary to have some kind of global providers that can be easily accessed through the context on many pages in the application

I'm trying to make a workaround for changing global providers in the application when the authorization state changes. I get an error when switching pages. Please let me know what are the options to solve this problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class AutProvired extends ValueNotifier<String?> {
  AutProvired(super.value);

  void aut() {
    value = 'user';
    navigatorKey.currentState?.pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext context) => const HomeView()), (route) => false);
  }

  void exit() {
    value = null;
    navigatorKey.currentState?.pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext context) => const AutView()), (route) => false);
  }
}

class DataProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String user;

  DataProvider({
    required this.user,
  });
}

class AutViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {}

void main() {
  runApp(RootApp.create());
}

class RootApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const RootApp._();

  static Widget create() => MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (BuildContext context) => AutProvired(null)),
        ],
        child: const RootApp._(),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AutProvired autProvired = context.watch();

    final String? user = autProvired.value;

    if (user == null) {
      return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (BuildContext context) => AutViewModel()),
        ],
        child: const App(),
      );
    }

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (BuildContext context) => DataProvider(user: user)),
      ],
      child: const App(),
    );
  }
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AutProvired autProvired = context.read();

    final String? user = autProvired.value;

    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: user == null ? const AutView() : const HomeView(),
    );
  }
}

class AutView extends StatelessWidget {
  const AutView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AutViewModel autViewModel = context.watch();
    // ...
    autViewModel;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final AutProvired autProvired = context.read();

            autProvired.aut();
          },
          child: const Text('Aut'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final DataProvider dataProvider = context.watch();
    // ...
    final String user = dataProvider.user;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(user),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              final AutProvired autProvired = context.read();

              autProvired.exit();
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```